# How to access the output of a program via pipe in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to pipe the output of a python script using os.popen() . Here my python script :

**sample.py**

```
while(True):
   print("hello")
```

python version : 3.6.7
os : ubuntu 18.04

My script  to do the process :

```
import os
import types
def sample_function():
    pipe = os.popen('python3 /home/gomathi/sample.py')
    while(True):
        a = pipe.readline()
        yield a
s=sample_function()
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

It works well for the above code.Now the problem is , i have changed the **sample.py** as follows :

**sample.py**

```
print("hello")
```

It just print blank for the entire screen and continues printing blank  characters . What went wrong with my code ? What changes to be made in my code to work for the above sample.py ?

Comment: Use the subprocess module. The docs come with many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `subprocess` module, with the same function `Popen` and redirect the output and the error to the `print` function of your main .py file.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
command = ['python3', '/home/gomathi/sample.py']
process = Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline() #variable_name_changed
    print(line)
```

Comment: I'm getting error in stdout (undefined variable) in line 5

Comment: My fault, I wrote an equal sign `=` instead of a point `.`.
Solved, now, it should works.

Answer (score 2):

Your new `sample.py` ends, but you keep reading from the pipe. So you're getting empty strings.